# Query result in Realm.js comes aleatory with string fields in upper case

Tags: android, react-native, realm-migration

I'm using **Realm 1.2.0** in a **React Native** project for **Android**, and depending on the query restriction (using filtered() function) the string fields in my result set come all in upper case.

Example:

```
realm.objects('AdminUnit').filtered('parentId = ' + id);
```

returns an object containing (id, name, parentId), where name is of string type.

Depending on the ID, the name field of all objects are in UPPER CASE.

I have already checked the table content and the data is not capitalized, and this same behavior happens in other queries of different tables.

Does anyone knows how to make the result comes as it is in the table?